# Grouping with PowerBI Embedded

Tags: grouping, powerbi-embedded

I am in desperate need of some help and am hoping one of you can help me think of a work around. We are using PowerBI embedded and I know that the grouping/binning option is not an option here but rather only in desktop mode.

What we really need is for the table on the left in the image below to be able to be represented as the table on the right.

[image]

Has anyone ran into this issue before and solved it? Is there any known reason why this isn't currently supported?

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Create a new column with value "Product A" and "All Others". Then use GROUP BY.

Comment: @mkRabbani - how can I do this via the PowerBI Service? As far as I can see this is only doable via the Desktop